# When i am using alert, toggleClass is working otherwise not. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

The Question is when i am using alert, toggleClass works otherwise not.

Here is my code

```
$(testParentSpan).click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("parent1");
      alert("test is click");
});
```

where as testParentSpan is variable storing whole span tag

```
var testParentSpan = htmlLabelElementObj.parentElement.parentElement.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild;
```

**css**

```
span.parent1 span.dynatree-icon {
    background-image: url('closefolder.png') !important;
}

/*span.parent1[class~='dynatree-expanded'] */
span.dynatree-expanded[class~=parent1] span.dynatree-icon  {
    background-image: url('openfolder1.png') !important;
}
```

I tried

```
$(testParentSpan).bind('click','.class',function(){ 
    $(this).toggleClass("parent1");
      alert("test is click");
});
```

same effect no change. when i use alert it works otherwise not.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for it?

Comment: actually i am working on live so not able to fiddle it. dynamic getting node of dynatree from iframe and changing node icon using toggle css. here i am getting span of that node.i posted css also.

Comment: Guys i think added in normal javascript function -> jquery click function that's why it is calling only on alert. Now what should i do.?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi can you help me out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasonable thing that comes to mind is that you might have some code that changes the css classes or does some other dom manipulation, and that code delays it's execution in the alert sceanario - alert blocks the control flow. From the info supplied in the question I can only suggest to debug in order to track where the code that generates this race condition occurs...

Comment: if i am not using alert the event is not triggered. how to trigger instead of alert? and thanks for answering my question

Comment: you need to figure out *why* the event is not triggered in the alert scenario. try to debug and find out what code you have on that page that might influence it. example: you might have some code that removes the ".class" class from that element to which you bind the click event, and that code only executes "in time" when the alert blocks the control flow.

Comment: I added normal javascript function -> jquery click function that's why it is calling only on alert. Now what should i do.?